# How to pass header Information as key value pair to consume rest service using spring

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, webservice-client, resttemplate

I got a url of web service which returns values in json format but it needs header information in get request as key value pair e.g. I need to pass Emp_code as key and 'xyz' as value to get details of all employees in postman.

```
private static void getEmployees()
```

{
    final String uri = "http://abc/springrestexample/employees";

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

System.out.println(result);
```

}

In above code how can I pass header info(key-value) so as to consume service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add headers to your request by using the following example:

```
org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.add("yourHeaderKey", "yourHeadeerValue");
org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
```

And then issuing this call to your restTemplate:

```
    restTemplate.exchange(uri, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity , String.class);
```